# Is it worth my time producing ldpi assets for Android applications these days?

Tags: android

I'm currently building an application for Android (a game). So far, I've created assets for all devices, from ldpi all the way up to xhdpi. I'm building the application for Android 2.2 and above.

Should I stop producing ldpi images?

It would cut down the time it takes to produce the graphics fairly significantly. On top of this, I don't think that very many devices (commonly used) these days actually fall into the ldpi category.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only 3.1% of phones with `ldpi` screens (as of 1st Jan 2016). [Here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) is the statistics about devices and their screens. You can decide whether to support them or not.

Comment: Very interesting. 2.3% is quite a significant amount. I will continue producing ldpi assets. Thanks!

Comment: Odd, I have seen someone else say `2%`.  I am seeing `9.2%` as of `Nov. 1st 2013`.  Why would `ldpi` have gone up since you answered this?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think it is because of cheap devices in some countries. For example in my country (Russia) there is really cheap (50$ without contract) devices with ldpi density

Comment: Any way - we now provide mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi[- optional xxhdpi] - and android generate ldpi resources quite good - if you can say "good" about picture on ldpi :)

Comment: Here is the official Google info on this:   http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html    5.8% on Nov 2014

Comment: Update: 2.7% on March 2016

Answer (score 0):

It is suitable to use all image packs, because if most devices support MDPI, but you would be losing market devices with low resolution.  Use LDPI.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you like. you could set a in code aspect ratio resizer, and size all the images accordingly when loading them. So no matter what screen you play on, they take up the same percentage of it. This significantly cut down graphic time, and looks great.

another way you could do it, is get Paint.net and simply build the largest graphics first. Then go into Image and Resize, and set the resize to by the ratio difference, say 75%. save this and you are done. Should cut the entire time down significantly as well, and also looks great.

I have done it both ways, and you cant tell the difference.

I have always built my code so that it fits the game to the screen.
for example in a sidescrolling fighter if a character is 5/8 the screens height, and 3/12 the screen width on my testing device, and it looks great>>> you can do a little math, figure out the h/w ratio of the screen any user is playing on, and adjust the image at load time so that no matter the device your image will take up the percentage of the screen you intended it to.

Answer (score 0):

True, but to build your brand image, you have to do the job perfectly, for everyone. Even if there are a few tens of users who use low dpi, it's totally worth it. :-)