# Number of 4.0 and above devices using ldpi assets in android?

Tags: android

I have seen [Is it worth my time producing ldpi assets for Android applications these days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425283/is-it-worth-my-time-producing-ldpi-assets-for-android-applications-these-days) and also http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens but I cannot find statistics per version.

Is this available anywhere?
The reason I ask is that I believe that most ldpi devices are using old android versions, something that I would like to verify before dropping ldpi assets.

Comment: There are no specifics on screen sizes with Android versions. However you can assume that during the last years screens got cheaper and there are less ldpi screens on the market. Personally, I wouldn't bother with developing for ldpi, but when you design your application correctly it shouldn't be a problem when scaling.

Comment: I've stopped using ldpi, as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) there's only 8.1% of the small devices that use ldpi resources, which you probably can imagine,  are not a lot

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a list of android devices and their specs, including android version and screen density:

http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/record/lod.htm

hope it helps you.